# mvn build keeps checking nexus repos not matter what I put in pom file

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, pom.xml, ksqldb

I am trying to access some jar files by including dependencies in the pom.  The problem is I get error not found in my corporate nexus repo. How do I tell Maven not to look only in http://sl-quality.mycompany.com/nexus/content/groups/public/ for the dependencies? And where earth is the url defined?

```
 Could not resolve dependencies for project com.mycompany.myproj:mycompany-service:jar:1.0- 
 SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact io.confluent.ksql:ksqldb-api-client:jar:0.11.0 in nexus 
 (http://sl-quality.mycompany.com/nexus/content/groups/public/



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
   http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.mycompany.myapp</groupId>
    <artifactId>com-mycompany-app</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
    <ksqldb.version>0.11.0</ksqldb.version>
    <!-- Maven properties for compilation -->
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <!-- jhipster-needle-maven-repository -->
        <repository>
            <id>ksqlDB</id>
            <name>ksqlDB</name>
            <url>https://ksqldb-maven.s3.amazonaws.com/maven/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>confluent</id>
            <name>Confluent</name>
            <url>https://jenkins-confluent-packages-beta-maven.s3.amazonaws.com/6.1.0-beta200715032424/1/maven/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.confluent.ksql</groupId>
            <artifactId>ksqldb-api-client</artifactId>
            <version>${ksqldb.version}</version>
        </dependency>
   </dependencies>
```

I have no idea why it always goes to nexus as this is no where mentioned in my pom file. I could install in my local repo but not sure what app jar files need to be pulled for it to work as two repos needed to be added.

I would like to know exactly what jar files i can extract to put in my local repo. Thanks

Comment: What is in your settings.xml? (C:/Users/<Youruser>/.m2/settings.xml) for windows

Comment: So your right it was missing it but when i add the two other repos it still only checks that same one. If I remove it then I get errors from the other jars ..

Comment: So I really need to keep the first mirror because it has all my corporate repo stuff. How can I use additional repos to get the this one or two additional jar files that I need?

Comment: I edited to ad settings.xml but because I have few points no one has approved it yet. But basically your right but I cannot just swap out the mirror because i need that one. I need a way to use the two repos somehow to just download the jar!

Answer (score 2):

Repository is generally configured in your settings file located in `C:/Users/Youruser/.m2/settings.xml` on windows

Check the mirror and corresponding repository tags for example - your settings.xml will probably look like this

```
 <mirror>
   <id>nexus</id>
   <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
   <url>http://sl-quality.mycompany.com/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
 </mirror>
```

Change this url to point to another repo, perhaps an external non corporate one such as `http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2`

EDIT:
I think this is what you want

```
<mirrors>
  <mirror>
    <id>nexus</id>
    <mirrorOf>*,!ksqlDB</mirrorOf>
    <url>http://sl-quality.mycompany.com/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
  </mirror>
</mirrors>

 <!-- Add repository for your other repo to filter on above -->
 <profile>
  <id>nexus</id>
 <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>ksqlDB</id>
      <url>https://ksqldb-maven.s3.amazonaws.com/maven/</url>
      <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </snapshots>
    </repository>
</profile>
```

```
<!-- add at bottom inside </settings> -->
<activeProfiles>
 <activeProfile>nexus</activeProfile>
</activeProfiles>
```

Add more repos as needed and filter above where necessary. I believe (not tested) that you can apply the same exclusions to mirrors instead of repositories personally I prefer using repository tags and having profiles setup.

Comment: <activeProfiles>
    <!--make the profile active all the time -->
    <activeProfile>nexus</activeProfile>
</activeProfiles>
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>nexus</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <repositories>

Comment: I notice that only one profile is active which is nexus? maybe this is why?

Comment: I added the mirrors but only nexus is looked at

Comment: I dont know what to put in here? <activeProfiles>
        <!--make the profile active all the time -->
        <activeProfile>nexus</activeProfile>

    </activeProfiles>

Comment: comma list or how to create a profile for the mirrored repo? is the active profiles a comma separated list?

Comment: If you have a mirror entry like the one Sim mentioned, then *everything* is redirected to that mirror. It does not help to add a second mirror.

Comment: Ok, but I need to go against all three really not just one. How do I get jars from multiple repos if I can only mirror one?

Comment: When. I exclude the first one I am missing all kinds of stuff from my corporate repo that I also need ...

Comment: I think it should be clear by now that I want a jar file that is not in the mirrored repo? What should I do?

Comment: So I have heard that I should not use * for each repo. How exactly do I exclude repos that are in nexus there are a bunch of them added in profile

Comment: so I think I can have more than one mirror but use exclusions.